# ZF2 UTF8 Characters in URL / Router

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2, I am trying to use a route with UTF8 characters in it but am not having any luck. When using UTF8 characters, I always get the error "The requested URL could not be matched by routing."

My route looks like this:

```
'contact-us' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/kundtjänst/',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'contact-us',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

And I am certain that it is the "ä" character that is giving me problems since when I take it out (and change the URL), it works. How can I use these characters (Swedish, Norwegian, and Estonian) in routes with ZF2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use urlencoded characters:

```
'route' => '/kundtj%C3%A4nst/',
```